# How to make the check box as true in react for the following code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react using it with node v18.18.2:
Now how to check the checkbox here:
Sharing the following code:

```
    <Controller
      defaultValue={true}
      name="graph_outline"
      control={methods.control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <>
          <br />
          <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox {...field} />} label="Graph Outline" />
        </>
      )}
    />
```

the answer is as given below:

```
<Controller
  defaultValue={true}
  name="graph_outline"
  control={methods.control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <>
      <br />
      <InputLabel>Graph Outline</InputLabel>
      <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox {...field} checked={true} />} label="Graph Outline" />
    </>
  )}
/>
```

But the issue is that value do not get updated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the following changes checked the checkbox:

```
<Controller
  defaultValue={true}
  name="graph_outline"
  control={methods.control}
  render={({ field }) => (
    <>
      <br />
      <InputLabel>Graph Outline</InputLabel>
      <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox {...field} checked={true} />} label="Graph Outline" />
    </>
  )}
/>
```